Power Apps Display Graph in HTML Text
I am trying to display a Python Plotly graph in HTML text in PowerApps. The data for the graph is grabbed via an API. and stored in a collection as a JSON object.
I am not sure of the feasibility of this task, so I wanted to try it with a very simple Plotly graph. Here is the code I have that works outside of the Power Apps environment:
"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Plotly Chart Example</title>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='plot' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div> <!-- Plot div -->
    <script>
        // Example data from Plotly documentation
        var data = [{
            x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y: [20, 14, 23],
            type: 'bar'
        }];
       
        // Plotly layout
        var layout = {
            title: 'Bar Chart Example',
            xaxis: {
                title: 'Animals'
            },
            yaxis: {
                title: 'Count'
            }
        };
 
        // Create the plot
        Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout);
    </script>
</body>
</html>"

When I put this into the PowerApps HTML text element, I do not get any errors. However, the graph does not get displayed. I have found a way to get a Matplotlib graph shown when I encode it as a base64 string, but that doesn't seem to work for Plotly. Does anyone know if it is possible to display a plotted graph (even a static one) in PowerApps? If so, I would love some help as how to do to so!
